# ganz + Dativ als Präposition?

Tags: word-usage, preposition, sentence-structure, dative

> Ganz dem Motto "Man lebt zur zweimal" habt ihr es geschafft.

Ich bin auf diesen Satz gestoßen, da hat mich diese Verwendung von **ganz** sofort neugierig gemacht. Kann mir jemand mal erklären, was das heißt und in welchem Kontext es sich anwenden lässt?
So wie **ganz** im Satz eingebaut ist, wirkt es wie eine Präposition (die Dativ verlangt), doch ich habe nirgendwo Näheres darüber gefunden. Meine Annahme wäre in Richtung **laut** oder **gemäß**. Zu weit daneben?

Danke im Voraus für jede Aufklärung.

Comment: Ich denk hier fehlt einfach ein Wort: "Ganz nach dem Motto". Oder: "Ganz dem Motto folgend"... Vielleicht hat sich eine Weglassung auch irgendwo eingebürgert, aber die Bedeutung muss dieselbe sein.

Answer (score 2):

Tatsächlich gibt es diese Form - Man nennt sie *dativus finalis* und sie gehört zu den praktisch ausgestorbenen Verwendungen des Dativs, die das Deutsche aus dem Lateinischen übernommen hat. Typische Beispiele dafür sind

> Er lebt nur seiner Arbeit

Hier drückt der Dativ einen Zweck aus. Wie gesagt, eher gehoben und auch da nicht mehr besonders verbreitet, von vielen Muttersprachlern heute sogar als "falsch" betrachtet und nur noch in Wendungen wie z.B. Trinksprüchen

> Dir zum Wohle!

erhalten. Ich würde sagen: Das muss man nicht kennen...

Comment: Wieso soll "Motto" im Beispiel  eine "finale" Bedeutung haben?

Comment: @Alazon Das Motto zu verfolgen?

Comment: Warum kann man *ganz* nicht weglassen? Warum funktioniert eine Umschreibung mit *zum Motto …* oder *für das Motto …* nicht?

Comment: @DavidVogt Vielleicht nur zum Nachdruck, also im Sinne von "dem Motto wortgetreu folgen"?

Answer (score 1):

Dieser Satz ist nicht korrekt. Er ist falsch. In ihm fehlt ein Wort:

> Ganz **nach** dem Motto "Man lebt zur zweimal" habt ihr es geschafft.

Das Wort *»ganz«* am Beginn des Satzes ist ein Adverb, dass den Grad der Übereinstimmung mit dem Motto beschreibt. Es kann z.B. durch *»völlig«* oder *»vollständig«* ersetzt werden. Der Teil *»nach dem Motto«* ist eine adverbiale Bestimmung.